# Swap file names

Tags: c#, file, xamarin.android

I am making an app in [MonoDroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)#Related_projects) (C#) and I am trying to swap two files names, and it isn't working.

Below is my code

```
String x = file1.Name;
String y = file2.Name;

File f = new File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Images/" + vehicleid + "/" + "temp" + ".jpg");

File tempfile1 = new File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Images/" + vehicleid + "/" + x);
File tempfile2 = new File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Images/" + vehicleid + "/" + y);

file1.RenameTo(file2);
file2.RenameTo(tempfile1);
```

Comment: What isn't working? Which are the two files?

Comment: If you're trying swap anything, at least 3 operations need to happen, swap 1 to temp, swap 2 to 1, swap temp to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried System.IO.File.Move() ?

If the old and new files are on the same physical disk, the file is renamed. Otherwise, it is physically moved (copy made in new location, then - if that was successful - the old file deleted).